# After clicking the nth item, how do I manipulate another nth element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery and wanting to target the nth <li> in a list after clicking the nth link.

```
<ul id="targetedArea">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
<div id="clickedItems">
  <a></a>
  <a></a>
  <a></a>
  <a></a>
</div>
```

I can target them individually, but I know there must be a faster way by passing which <a> element I clicked on.

```
$("#clickedItem a:eq(2)").click(function() {
  $("#targetedArea:eq(2)").addClass('active');
  return false;
});
```

Cheers,
Steve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about something like this:

```
$('#clickedItems a').click(function() {
// figure out what position this element is in
   var n = $('#clickedItems a').index($(this) );
// update the targetedArea
   $('#targetedArea li:eq('+n+')').html('updated!');
   return false;
});
```

assuming a 1:1 relationship between your `<a>` and `<li>` elements it will update the appropriate `<li>`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not directly answering your question, but maybe you're making it more difficult than it is.

Give each of the A and LI elements an ID, and make the IDs so you can infer them from each other. As soon as an A is clicked, you immediately know the LI's ID and can refer to it directly.

As a side effect, this is more efficient than any clever jQuery that might do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if jquery has something like this in mootools

```
$$('a.clickedItems').addEvent('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('targetedArea').getChildren()[this.getAllPrevious().length].addClass('selected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#clickedItems a').click(function() {
    // you probably want to turn off the currently active one
    $('#targetedArea li.active').removeClass("active");

    // count the links previous to this one and make the corresponding li active
    $('#targetedArea li:eq(' + $(this).prevAll('a').length + ')').addClass("active");

    // prevent the browser from going to the link
    return false;
});
```